# Add slide control in magento2 frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend

How can I add a slide control in the frontend using the Magento UI library or any other way?

I am not talking about an image slider I talking about a control slider
Something like: [boostrap slide](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/)

Comment: Were exactly do you want to add this? initially you will need to require the bootstrap slider script and jquery to load it on your page but little more info as to location would help

Comment: Try this module https://marketplace.magento.com/weltpixel-m2-weltpixel-owl-carousel-slider.html - I recommend this module.

Comment: @St3phan Please read the whole question before comment it

Comment: @DavaGordon I am adding these controls in the home page but I am building a module so I can put the code anyware phtml, htm knockout, xml or cms page I don't mind. I am looking a solution with in the magento elements as I don't want to introduce confilict just to add a simple slider control that it is probably with in the magento core already.

Comment: i have posted possible answer for you below

Answer (score 0):

To import external library, usually there are 2 ways: **CDN** or **download the whole JS library using npm**. As this library provided a CDN method, I'd suggest you to use CDN method as it's much simplier.

1. In your active theme, let's say, `Vender_Theme`. Go to file `app/design/frontend/Cleargo/k11/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`, add the following content:

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
           <!--CSS-->
           <css src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" src_type="url" />
           <!--JS-->
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js" src_type="url" />
       </head>
       <!--Rest of codes-->
   </page>
   ```
2. The first step can make sure you can use this library in every pages. Next, you can implement the library in the template file you want. I took Example 1 in the link you provided:

   ```
   //HTML Part
   <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>
   //jQuery part
   <script>
       require([
           'jquery',
           'jquery/ui'
       ], function($){
           $('#ex1').slider({
               formatter: function(value) {
                   return 'Current value: ' + value;
               }
           });
       });
   </script>
   //CSS Part
   <style>
   #ex1Slider .slider-selection {
       background: #BABABA;
   }
   </style>
   ```

   - Note: Make sure you have bootstrap imported into your theme. If not, you need to import it first.
   - Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

Comment: Thanks for answeriny @PY Yick but I am trying to use the Magento UI library.  I try before soemthing very similar to your solution but brings lots of incompatibilities at the requirejs level.  Thats why i have my own bootstrap less only with the components I need. but even though If I add on top of this the external library conflicts with jquery UI and with the slider in the magento UI calendar. must be a more elegant way to do it with the Magento UI otherwise I will change the design to a dropbox

Answer (score 0):

```
require([
    'jquery',
    "jquery/ui",
    'domReady!'
], function($){
    $("#slider").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 50,
            values: [ 1, 50 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
            },
            change: function( event, ui ) {
            }
        });
        $( "#field" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});

    <input type="text" id="field" readonly>
<div id="slider"></div>
```